# Help With SQL Query - Sub Query Using INTERBASE 

Tags: sql, select, firebird, interbase

I have the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM
              ( select distinct
                      r1.rep_code,
                      r1.contact_id,
                      c1.Name,
                      e1.year_num,
                      e1.period_num
                   from
                      entry e1
                         join rep r1 ON e1.rep_code = r1.rep_code
                            join contact c1 on r1.contact_id = c1.contact_id
                   where
                          e1.entry_type = 'SJOB'
                      and e1.age = 0 )
```

I keep getting an error on line 3

```
Token unknown - line 3, char 15
select
```

can you please advice, by the way im using **interbase IBConsole** !!

Comment: Please give a more descriptive title to your question. And please specify in the tags what database you are using.

Comment: I tested your query in firebird and it works.

Comment: @OrhanCinar any ideas why it is not working on my machine ?

Comment: @c11ada what is your IB version ?

Comment: @OrhanCinar how do i find out which version im using ?

Comment: Try an freeware IB manager for this query. May be the problem is at IBConsole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Interbase [does not support derived tables](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=52050) (`SELECT FROM (SELECT)`). Or, at least, the version you are using (I cannot be sure, it's been a while since I don't work with Interbase). This feature was added in Firebird 2.0. You have two options here:

- Change your approach so that you don't use `SELECT FROM (SELECT)` (derived tables)

  **OR**
- *Upgrade* to Firebird

If you have autonomy for that, you should definitively go with option #2.

BTW, Firebird does not require you to declare an alias for your derived table, although that will end up being necessary if you will have your derived table JOINED with other table(s)/derived table(s)

Answer (score 3):

InterBase doesn't support derived tables. But they give you no benefit for this query, so just get rid of it:

```
              select distinct
                  r1.rep_code,
                  r1.contact_id,
                  c1.Name,
                  e1.year_num,
                  e1.period_num
               from
                  entry e1
                     join rep r1 ON e1.rep_code = r1.rep_code
                        join contact c1 on r1.contact_id = c1.contact_id
               where
                      e1.entry_type = 'SJOB'
                         and e1.age = 0
```

...will give you the same results as a derived table would in this case..

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the subquery an alias.

```
SELECT *
FROM
          ( select distinct
                  r1.rep_code,
                  r1.contact_id,
                  c1.Name,
                  e1.year_num,
                  e1.period_num
               from
                  entry e1
                     join rep r1 ON e1.rep_code = r1.rep_code
                        join contact c1 on r1.contact_id = c1.contact_id
               where
                      e1.entry_type = 'SJOB'
                  and e1.age = 0 ) AS tbl
```

Comment: Iv already tried that, but I still get an error of Token unknown - line 3, char 4 SELECT

Comment: @c11ada - And what database are you using?

Comment: @Oded IBConsole is InterBase Console

Comment: Im using Interbase, i put it at the end of my question. sorry I should have made it more clear and put in the title

Comment: @c11ada - Check that all the tables and columns in the query exist and that you have permissions to read them.

Comment: even if I do SELECT * in the sub query, I still get an error on line 3

Comment: @c11ada - Like I said, check that the columns actually exist on the tables, and that the tables actually exist. This including having the correct permissions on them.

Comment: @Oded im 100% those columns exist on them tables and I have administrator  permission on the database

Comment: @Adrian how do i find out what version of IB im using ??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
              ( select distinct
                      r1.rep_code,
                      r1.contact_id,
                      c1.Name,
                      e1.year_num,
                      e1.period_num
                   from
                      entry e1
                         join rep r1 ON e1.rep_code = r1.rep_code
                            join contact c1 on r1.contact_id = c1.contact_id
                   where
                          e1.entry_type = 'SJOB'
                      and e1.age = 0 ) AS TABLE1
```

Comment: please format your code... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

I got this error:

> #
>   1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
              ( select distinct
                      r1.rep_code,
                      r1.contact_id,
                      c1.Name,
                      e1.year_num,
                      e1.period_num
                   from
                      entry e1
                         join rep r1 ON e1.rep_code = r1.rep_code
                            join contact c1 on r1.contact_id = c1.contact_id
                   where
                          e1.entry_type = 'SJOB'
                      and e1.age = 0 ) AS entries
```

Comment: how to format my code... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks